# Exporting js yup validationschema object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, yup

I am trying to create the validation schema on yup as a separate function.
I am getting this error:

***Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')***

*validations/ValidationSchema.js*

```
import yup from "yup";

const validationLoginSchema = yup.object({
  email: yup
    .string("Enter your email")
    .email("Enter a valid email")
    .required("Email is required"),
  password: yup
    .string("Enter your password")
    .min(1, "Password should be of minimum 1 characters length")
    .required("Password is required"),
});

module.exports = {
  validationLoginSchema,
};
```

*Login Component*

```
import { validationLoginSchema } from "../validations/ValidationSchema";

 ...
   const formik = useFormik({

validationSchema: validationLoginSchema, // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way to export

```
module.exports = {
  validationLoginSchema,
};
```

then this way to import

```
const validationLoginSchema = require('../validations/ValidationSchema')
```

or this way to export

```
export default validationLoginSchema;
```

then import

```
import  validationLoginSchema from "../validations/ValidationSchema";
```

Comment: I tried, but still the same error.

Comment: The same error is again

Comment: @n9p4
``import  validationLoginSchema from "../validations/ValidationSchema";``
remove curly brackets